# ¿Cómo se llama el efecto de llamar a las cosas por el nombre de una marca conocida?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

¿Cómo se llama (si es que tiene un nombre) al efecto por el que un artículo es denominado por el nombre de una marca o fabricante, en lugar del propio nombre del artículo?

A veces una marca se impone tanto en la venta, distribución o fabricación de un producto, o simplemente en el vocabulario popular, que ese producto empieza a ser más conocido por ese nombre que le da la marca del fabricante o la marca en sí que por el nombre genérico del producto.

Algunos ejemplos:

1. "La tapa del *delco*". [Delco](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribuidor_(autom%C3%B3vil)), una empresa de General Motors, fue la primera en fabricar *distribuidores*, que son un elemento de encendido en los motores. La gente en lugar de decir "la tapa del distribuidor" solía decir "la tapa del *delco*".
   Mirad [este enlace](https://consejos.oscaro.es/cambiar-tapa-de-delco-automovil.html), en el que se hace referencia al "distribuidor" y la palabra "delco" no aparece para nada. Sin embargo, fijáos el la URL: "cambiar-tapa-de-**delco**", ya que pretende capturar las búsquedas de "cambiar tapa delco" en Internet.
2. En mi casa siempre decíamos "Me voy a tomar un *Cola Cao*" aunque siempre fuimos de *Nesquick*. No decíamos "cacao en polvo" ni nada parecido. Le llamábamos por el nombre de la marca más conocida, incluso si era distinta a la que realmente usábamos.
3. Cuando yo daba clases de dibujo técnico (y he de admitir que de eso hace casi unos veinte años) había que pasar los dibujos a tinta, por lo que tenías que comprarte un "rotring". En realidad lo que necesitabas era una "pluma técnica", pero se las conocía por el nombre de una de las empresas que las fabricaban: [Rotring](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotring). Si ibas a la papelería el dependiente, que ya estaba al tanto de este efecto, podía mostrarte unas plumas más económicas (de otras marcas) que las Rotring, porque entendía que no necesariamente le estabas pidiendo esa marca específica.
4. Es común oir "Usa la *minipimer*", que no es sino una batidora de mano. Mirad estos ejemplos: [ejemplo #1](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licuadora_de_mano), [ejemplo #2](https://espanol.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080610111255AAw3F6a); con especial atención al primer enlace que dice:

   > La empresa [...] mantuvo el nombre original del artefacto: [Minipimer], que se ha convertido en el nombre común de este tipo de batidoras.

Y añado: "aunque las fabrique otro que no sea Braun/Minipimer".

5. Análogos al anterior: "Receta para la thermomix". Thermomix es el nombre del fabricante más conocido de este tipo de *robots de cocina*. A veces te puedes encontrar con instrucciones que son específicas para este modelo o fabricante, y otras veces son completamente "genéricas" pero se refieren al electrodoméstico por la marca. De igual manera, "la *singer*" denominaba antes a una máquina de coser, porque todas eran marca Singer.
6. Similar, aunque posiblemente mucho menos extendido que alguno de los anteriores, el decir "una rebanada de pan *Bimbo*" en lugar de "pan de molde" o "pan de sandwich", porque *Bimbo* era (es) una de las empresas más conocidas o con mayor presencia (ahora hay muchas más "marcas blancas" que antes). De manera similar "Petit suisse" era un "mini yogur" destinado a los más pequeños. Danone en su momento les cambió el nombre a "Danoninos", pero por mucho tiempo "*petisuis*" era como se le llamaba al "mini yougur" de la marca que fuera.
7. "No llores, que se te corre el *Rimmel*". "Trucos para que no se te corra el *Rimmel*". Rimmel era la marca más conocida de máscara de pestañas.

Entiendo que a muchos estos ejemplos les sonarán completamente *alienígenas*. A algunos por la diferencia de país y a otros por la diferencia de edad (servidor hace tiempo que peina canas...). En cualquier caso, creo que hay suficientes para ilustrar el efecto. ¿Tiene nombre?

Comment: ¡Buena! Aquí hay otro ejemplo: "Confort"- papel higiénico en Chile. ¿Alguien tiene el dato de un wiki de éstas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

El proceso se llama **[Vulgarización de marcas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulgarizaci%C3%B3n_de_marca)**.

La vulgarización de las marcas es un proceso más bien negativo para las marcas que representan. En el aspecto legal, se inicia por una tercera persona. Generalmente por un empresa que se ve afectada por el uso generalizado. Una vez vulgarizada la marca, el nombre puede ser utilizado por cualquiera de manera indistinta.

Ciertamente, es un ejemplo de **lexicalización** en cuanto al hecho de que se incorpora un palabra nueva al lenguaje derivado de un uso funcional. En esta caso una marca pierde la representatividad del producto específico y se vuelve genérica.

Lexicalización  es también la conversion de siglas, como por ejemplo: IMSS, PYME, AFORE, NIP, LÁSER, IVA, IFE.

Comment: Gracias. Añadí un enlace a "vulgarización de marca". Resulta que este efecto es un caso de lexicalización, sí, y supongo que de _Antonomasia_ en concreto (por el sentido de excelencia o relevancia). No me cuadra como _metonimia_ porque no entiendo "la causa por el efecto" o "el efecto por la causa" en los casos de marcas. En cualquier caso es una _lexicalización de nombres propios_ pero el término de "vulgarización de marca" es más descriptivo que el más genérico de _lexicalización_.

Answer (score 6):

El proceso se llama **lexicalización**.

> Se da cuando una cualidad de algo o alguien que tiene cierto nombre propio se aplica a otras cosas o personas, es decir, se ha perdido la conexión directa con el nombre propio del que derivan, y puede ser tanto una metonimia como una antonomasia.
>
> Es un procedimiento habitual para la formación de nuevos nombres comunes y puede tener raíces históricas; por ejemplo, palacio es una lexicalización de Pallatium, nombre latino de la colina donde estaba el palacio de Augusto.
>
> Fuente: [wikilengua](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Lexicalizaci%C3%B3n)

Comment: Gracias! Bienvenido a Spanish.SE, por cierto. Gran aportación! Espero seguir viendo muchas aportaciones tuyas como esta en el futuro.

Answer (score 2):

El mecanismo sicológico y retórico general, que abarca estos casos y muchos otros, se llama **[metonimia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonimia)**: nombrar algo con una palabra que se refiere a otra cosa con la cual se relaciona.

Más específicamente se llama **[sinécdoque](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sin%C3%A9cdoque)** cuando la relación es general-específico, por ejemplo cuando se le dice "la visa" a la tarjeta de crédito, a pesar de Visa solo es un caso de tarjeta de crédito.

Answer (score 1):

La Antonomasia: es una figura retórica consistente en la sustitución de un nombre propio por una expresión reconocida universalmente.

Comment: Hola, bienvénido/a al sitio con tu primera contribución. Muy interesante esta respuesta  ¿podrías elaborarla un poco más? ¿Quizas puedas agregar una fuente autorizada y acaso ampliar en cuanto al mecanismo sustitutivo que propones como explicación?