# ¿Cuál es la marca registrada que lleva más tiempo aceptada como sustantivo en el DLE?

Tags: historia, sustantivos, dle

De cuando en cuando, empujada por el uso popular, la RAE incluye en el DLE, como palabras comunes, sustantivos que provienen de usar la marca comercial de un producto conocido como el nombre genérico de ese mismo producto.
Algunos ejemplos recientes serían: [táper](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Z7mZk4e), [pósit](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TnfXVsj), [clínex](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9TC9QRc).

Por esta pregunta: [¿Cómo se llama el efecto de llamar a las cosas por el nombre de una marca conocida?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19424/c%C3%B3mo-se-llama-el-efecto-de-llamar-a-las-cosas-por-el-nombre-de-una-marca-conoci), sabemos que este proceso puede llamarse "vulgarización de marca", "lexicalización" o incluso "sinécdoque", según el enfoque que hagamos.

Sin embargo, también es cierto que muchas de estas palabras dejan de usarse pasado un cierto tiempo, especialmente tras la desaparición de la marca asociada, y supongo que llegado ese momento la Academia las retira del diccionario.

Me asalta la curiosidad entonces: de todas las palabras basadas en marcas, ¿cuál es la más veterana del diccionario?

Comment: [Aquí](https://comaconcomilla.wordpress.com/2015/10/06/67-palabras-nacidas-a-partir-de-marcas-comerciales/) hay una lista con algunas candidatas a ser bastante antiguas pero no he encontrado referencias anteriores a los ejemplos de @ukemi, aunque también es posible que no haya buscado bien.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [*Parafina*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerosene#Illuminating_oil_from_coal_and_oil_shale): se registró por primera vez en 1853 (Domínguez), y en el DLE en **1884** (RAE).
- [*Vaselina*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaselina): 1895 (Zerolo), **1899** (RAE).
- [*Celuloide*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celuloide): 1895 (Zerolo), 1901 (Toro y Gómez), **1914** (RAE).
- [*Linóleo*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lin%C3%B3leo): **1914** (RAE).
- [*Maicena*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maicena): **1925** (RAE).

---

<sup>Hay unos ejemplos registrados más tempranos, pero en diccionarios aparte de la RAE:</sup>

<sup>• [*Adrenalina*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adrenalina): 1917 (Alemany y Bolufer), **1925** (RAE)

• [*Kerosene*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queroseno#Historia):  1917 (Alemany y Bolufer), **1927** (RAE)

• [*Zepelín*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirigible#Zepel%C3%ADn):    1917 (Alemany y Bolufer), 1918 (Rodríquez Navas), **1927** (RAE).

• [*Aspirina*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81cido_acetilsalic%C3%A1lico):    1917 (Alemany y Bolufer), 1918 (Rodríquez Navas), **1927** (RAE).

• [*Lanolina*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanolina):   1917 (Alemany y Bolufer), 1918 (Rodríquez Navas), **1970** (RAE).

• [*Heroína*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hero%C3%ADna#Etimolog%C3%ADa):    1917 (Alemany y Bolufer), 1918 (Rodríquez Navas), **1984** (RAE).</sup>

---

<sup>**Source:** https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Marcas_vulgarizadas</sup>

Comment: A mí me gusta _bamba_, que resulta que viene de Wamba http://dle.rae.es/?id=4vUNeiZ