# What's the name of a chupachús when it is not a Chupa-chups?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, definiciones, comida

Last Sunday I was negotiating a bribe to my oldest son so I could cut his fingernails. I offered a couple gummy beans but he said

> Quiero una *piruleta*. ¿Tenemos todavía *piruletas*?

I wasn't sure if we had the exact same thing he wanted or he was thinking of (which is often a problem with 5-year-olds) so I warned him that I seemed to remember we did have something, but maybe they were not *piruletas* and they were instead *chupachús*.

He didn't understand me, so I had to explain that the candy could be a ball, instead of a flat disc. I wasn't surprised he didn't understand, since he hasn't been exposed to the "Chupa-Chups" brand, which is a Spanish one.

Later, I checked the definitions in the dictionary:

> **[piruleta](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TBnTIQd)**
>
> 1. f. Esp. Caramelo **plano**, generalmente de forma circular, con un palito que sirve de mango.

So *piruletas* are flat discs. The definition has the "Esp." for "España", but I guess that in other countries where they are called "paletas" for example it is the same.

Now, for the other one we have

> **[chupachups](https://dle.rae.es/?id=94925Lg)**
> Tb. chupachup, chupa-chups, chupa-chup, chupachús.
>
> **De Chupa Chups®, marca reg.** <sub>(the etymology is important for this question!)</sub>
>
> 1. m. Caramelo de forma **esférica**, con un palito que sirve de mango para poder chuparlo.

So that confirms that we call the "caramelo de forma esférica, con un palito" a *chupachup* (or any of its variants) due to a case of *[vulgarización de marca](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/19427/5481)*.

Interestingly, that entry in the dictionary doesn't say, like the one in *piruleta*, that the definition applies to Spain. I don't know if I should infer then that it applies to all the Spanish-speaking countries.

I know that there are other countries where the brand "Chupa-chups" is not known, but they have the same candy regardless.

My question is, what do you call the treat that consists in a *ball* of candy attached to a stick when you don't use the name of the brand? Are there other names for it in Spanish than any of the "*chupachús*" variants? Or is *Chupachús* (and its related variants) the only way to refere to this type of candy all across all Spanish-speaking countries?

Comment: I guess this is what I know as a lollipop?  I personally call it *un pudredientes* but that's just me....

Comment: In Spain you could also say [_pirulí_](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TBoMkF6), but it refers to a cone-shaped candy in a stick. That's why [Torrespaña](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrespa%C3%B1a) is also known as _El Pirulí_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

De acuerdo con lo indicado en el artículo [*chupachús*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chupach%C3%BAs) de la Wikipedia, así como contrastando con lo que comenta el Diccionario de americanismos, tenemos las siguientes palabras:

- [**bolón**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=Mr2Z7EgdUx0AL7YFF7i): *RD. Paleta de caramelo, de forma esférica y de gran tamaño*
- [**bombón**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=8GMQ70td5x0ARkMtt4s): *Ho, ES, Ni. Caramelo esférico con un palito incrustado en medio.*
- [**bon-bon-bum**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=jAJCwtAN5x0ADVMxKge): *De la marca comercial Bon-Bon-Bum®. Golosina de forma redonda con un palo en el centro que sirve de mango para chuparla.*
- [**chupachupa**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=JjYcMQzsPx0A5Uri0T2): *CR, Cu, Ve:O, Ur; f. CR. Golosina consistente en un caramelo sólido circular sostenido por un palito. (chupa-chupa).*
- [**chupachús**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=94925Lg): *De Chupa Chups®, marca reg. Caramelo de forma esférica, con un palito que sirve de mango para poder chuparlo.*
- [**chupeta**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=DimE9SUkKx0A2anp6JD): *RD, Ve; Cu, obsol. Caramelo sostenido por un palito que sirve de mango para poder chuparlo.*
- [**chupete**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=GhPiGackax0A7K0EuWu): *Gu, Ec, Pe, Bo, Ch:N. Golosina consistente en un caramelo sólido con forma de bola o de disco, sostenida por un palito.*
- [**chupetín**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=wU3UnAIE5x0Ai1u3L4M): *Pe, Bo, Py, Ar, Ur. Caramelo que se come sosteniéndolo por un palito hincado en su base.*
- [**colombina**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=KZqQRILgxx0AqKZIsHe): *Co. Caramelo con un palito que sirve de mango.*
- [**paleta**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=R1WeDNi8Cx0AjwvfOQd): *Mx, Ni, RD, PR, Bo:O, Py, Ar, Ur. Golosina consistente en un caramelo sólido circular sostenido por un palito.*

Si repartimos cada palabra entre los países que explican estas fuentes (y lo complementamos con la inteligencia colectiva a través de esta Community Wiki) podríamos afirmar que estas son las denominaciones según países de habla hispana:

### Argentina

- chupetín
- <s>paleta</s> <sub>es plana</sub>

### Bolivia

- chupete
- chupetín

#### Oeste

- paleta

### Chile

- chupete
- lolly pop
- kojak

### Colombia

- bon-bon-bum

[image]

- colombina
- piruleta

### Costa Rica

- poppy
- chupachupa

### Cuba

- chupachupa

### Ecuador

- chupete

### El Salvador

- bombón

### España

- chupachús

#### Asturias

- porra

### Guatemala

- bombón
- paleta

### Honduras

- bombón

### México

- paleta
- tutsi ??

### Nicaragua

- bombón
- paleta

### Paraguay

- chupetín
- paleta

### Perú

- chupete
- chupetín

### Puerto Rico

- paleta

### República Dominicana

- bolón
- paleta
- chupeta

### Uruguay

- chupetín
- chupachupa
- paleta

### Venezuela

- chupeta

#### Oeste

- chupachupa

Comment: @DGaleano te invoco :P ¿se usa _bombón_ en Colombia?

Comment: No quiero hablar por el 100% de la Argentina, pero en Buenos Aires `paleta` se refiere (¿casi?) exclusivamente a los chupetines planos, grandes (lo que en la pregunta se menciona como `piruleta`).

Comment: En Guatemala se dice bombon, paleta o menos comun, chupete. (Editando)

Comment: En Argentina el *chupetín* es esférico y la *paleta* es plana.

Comment: Elimino las referencias a los que son planos (gracias @pablodf76)

Comment: Gracias @mgarciaisaia, así lo modifiqué. Siéntete libre de editar si ves algo más mejorable, puse la respuesta en modo CW para facilitarlo.

Comment: @DarkCygnus ¡gracias! Recompuse un poco el formato

Comment: @alvalongo gracias por la edición! Nótese que el _Co._ en la definición de _bon bon bum_ es por Colombia, no por Company. Viene del Damer en http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=jAJCwtAN5x0ADVMxKge

Answer (score 3):

En Argentina se los conoce (indistintamente) como:

> chupetines

Del Diccionario de americanismos:

> [**chupetín**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=wU3UnAIE5x0Ai1u3L4M)
>
> I.    1. m. Pe, Bo, Py, Ar, Ur. Caramelo que se come sosteniéndolo por un palito hincado en su base.