# ¿Cuál es la palabra con más variantes admitidas por la RAE?

Tags: sinónimos, dle, curiosidades

En esta pregunta sobre caramelos con palo [What's the name of a chupachús when it is not a Chupa-chups?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/31882/14069) he descubierto que la palabra derivada de la marca *Chupa-Chups* tiene cinco variantes distintas:

> **[chupachups](https://dle.rae.es/?id=94925Lg)**
>
> Tb. **chupachup, chupa-chups, chupa-chup, chupachús.**
>
> `De`*`Chupa Chups®`*`, marca reg.`
>
> **1.** m. Caramelo de forma esférica, con un palito que sirve de mango para poder chuparlo.

A raíz de esto me ha surgido la duda: ¿cuál es la palabra con más variantes admitidas en el DLE? ¿Hay alguna forma de encontrar esa información sin tener que revisar todo el diccionario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He encontrado un ejemplo de una definición con 6 ortografías/variantes distintas:

> #### [**perojimén**](https://dle.rae.es/perojim%C3%A9n)
>
> Tb. [**pero jimén**](https://dle.rae.es/perojim%C3%A9n)  .
>
> 1. m. pedrojiménez.

> #### [**perojiménez**](https://dle.rae.es/perojim%C3%A9nez)
>
> Tb. [**pero jiménez**](https://dle.rae.es/perojim%C3%A9nez) .
>
> 1. m. pedrojiménez.

> #### [**pedrojiménez**](https://dle.rae.es/pedrojim%C3%A9nez#C3RzWw9)
>
> Tb. [**Pedro Jiménez**](https://dle.rae.es/pedrojim%C3%A9nez#C3RzWw9).
>
> 1. m. Variedad de uva propia de algunos pagos de Andalucía, y especialmente de Jerez de la Frontera, cuyos racimos son grandes, algo ralos y de granos esféricos, muy lisos, traslúcidos y de color dorado.
> 2. m. Vino dulce hecho de pedrojiménez.

Comment: ¿Cómo has encontrado eso? Al no estar todas las variantes en la misma entrada complica poder hacer una búsqueda a traves de un script y abre la posibilidad a que haya otras palabras con más variantes

Comment: @blonfu he googleado https://www.google.com/search?q=site:https://dle.rae.es+"Tb.+"

Comment: ¿Y con esa búsqueda tuviste suficiente? ¿Analizaste programáticamente o fuiste página a página mirando los resultados?

Comment: @fedorqui desafortunadamente no haha solo leí los primeros resultados - me resultó difícil formular una búsqueda 'wildcard' como `"Tb. *, *, *, *"` exitosamente en Google.

Comment: Lo mismo podríamos contactar con el autor de [DiRAE](https://dirae.es) (que creo que visitó el sitio en alguna ocasión, no recuerdo con qué usuario) para ver cómo consigue el _dump_ del DLE. Así sería fácil buscar estas cosas jeje

Answer (score 3):

> Publico esta respuesta en nombre de un benefactor anónimo.

---

El DLE ofrece una URL para consultar una palabra al azar (https://dle.rae.es/?w=&m=random).

En una distribución aleatoria, la probabilidad de que suceda lo mismo todas las veces se obtiene multiplicando la probabilidad por sí misma tantas veces como sea necesario. Por ejemplo: si la probabilidad de que al tirar un dado salga un seis es 1/6 = 16.67% y la de que no salga un seis es 5/6 = 83.33%, entonces la probabilidad de que salga un seis 10 veces seguidas es 1/6 * 1/6 * ... = 1/60,466,176 = ~0.000000017%, y la posibilidad que no salga ningún seis tras tirar 10 veces es 5/6 * 5/6 * ... = ~16.15%.

Según la RAE, la 23ª edición del DLE contiene más de 93 000 entradas; redondeando, unas 95 000.
La probabilidad que tiene cada una de esas 95 000 palabras de ser la devuelta por esa consulta, suponiendo que sea realmente aleatoria, es 1/95,000 = 0.00012%; y por tanto, la probabilidad de que una palabra concreta NO sea la devuelta al llamar a esa URL es del 99.9988%.
Supongamos que consultamos la URL arriba mencionada... 400 000 veces (obteniendo una palabra al azar cada vez, que puede haber salido ya antes o no). Repitiendo los cálculos, la probabilidad de que una palabra exista en el diccionario y NO salga nunca después de consultarlo al azar 400 000 veces es del 0.82%. O dicho de otra manera: **si una palabra existe en el DLE, la probabilidad de que aparezca *al menos una vez*, tras consultarlo al azar 400 000 veces, es del 99.18%**.

Pues bien: he consultado la URL de arriba esas 400 000 veces; seguramente más.
He encontrado muchas palabras con tres variantes (cuatro si contamos la forma "principal"); por ejemplo: *cenit, pteridofito, tamtam, lítote, suscriptor, askenazí*. Cada una de ellas me ha aparecido varias veces; cuando solo llevaba 150 000 consultas, algunas de ellas ya me habían aparecido hasta 10 veces.
También he encontrado la propia *chupachups*; la única palabra con cuatro (cinco) variantes. Tras 400 000 consultas, esta palabra me ha aparecido 3 veces.
La cuestión es: ¿me ha aparecido alguna palabra que supere a *chupachups* en número de variantes? Y la respuesta es...

**No.**

Por tanto, puedo afirmar, con más de un 99% de seguridad, que ***chupachups*** es la palabra con más variantes de todo el DLE.

Comment: Muchas gracias benefactor anónimo, un buen trabajo de investigación. Doy por buena la conclusión

Comment: Una pena que no haya una URL para consultar la *siguiente* palabra en el diccionario... eso nos habría permitido tener un 100% de seguridad en 95000 consultas ;)

Comment: Voy a quitar el check de esta respuesta y si no aprece otra candidata en unos días aceptaré la de @ukemi