# ¿Por qué se llama "kiko" al maíz tostado?

Tags: sustantivos, comida, nombres-propios

En casa comemos mucho fruto seco y tenemos especial fijación por el maíz tostado. Le llamamos *kikos*, que el DLE recoge:

> [**kiko**](https://dle.rae.es/kiko?m=form)
>
> 1. m. Grano de maíz tostado.

El Mapa de diccionarios me indica que se introdujo en el 1992.

Para mi sorpresa, [acabo de leer](https://twitter.com/optimotcat/status/1219228532028690435) que su uso en catalán se basa en la marca registrada Kikos®. ¿Es así también en castellano? ¿Qué fue antes? ¿Se trata de una [vulgarización de marcas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/19427/1674) o [lexicalización](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/19425/1674)?

Comment: Yo pensaba que venía de la expresión [_ponerse como el Quico_](https://dle.rae.es/Quico) (hipocorístico de _Francisco_), expresión que equivale a "hartarse de comer". Como los kikos son de esas cosas que cuando empiezas no paras, es fácil ponerse como el Quico con los kikos. De hecho en el DLE de 1992 la voz _kiko_ se recogía como _quico_.

Comment: yo siempre he llamado kiko no solo al maíz tostado sino a ciertos frutos secos/golosinas que vienen con sal (algunos), como cacahuetes

Comment: He encontrado referencias a los _kikos_ (usando esta grafía) como muy pronto en algunos ejemplares (de acceso no libre) de la hemeroteca de la Biblioteca Nacional de España, publicados en la década de 1960. La expresión _ponerse como el Quico_ es anterior (un caso en el CORDE de 1952), así que mi teoría es plausible.

Comment: En [Nombres provenientes de marcas](https://www.harcasostenible.com/2015/05/19/nombres-proveniente-de-marcas/) leo _Kikos es el nombre que la empresa Churruca dio a uno de sus primeros productos en 1932_. (Interesante, también comentan el caso de _bamba_, que viene de la marca de zapatillas de deporte Wamba en homenaje al rey visigodo).

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming': Es lo que pasó con la palabra italiana "pennarello", que nació como marca registrada, pero ahora es tan común que lo usan todas las marcas para llamar los rotuladores, como se ve en la fotografía de [esta respuesta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/5602/707).

Comment: Adiós a mi teoría entonces. :-) Veo que efectivamente la empresa Churruca se fundó en 1932. Sería interesante encontrar alguna noticia al respecto o publicidad de la marca en la hemeroteca.

Comment: @Charlie a todo esto sobrevuela pues otra pregunta _¿De dónde viene ponerse como el Quico?_ :) Parece que sí que el origen está en alguna comilona y un Francisco llamado Quico ([noticia que encontré](https://www.abc.es/historia/20141009/abci-ponerse-como-quico-201410081409.html))

Comment: Al final de ese último enlace se habla de un libro titulado "Cien cuentos populares españoles". Si el personaje de Quico es de un cuento popular, entonces sigue cabiendo la posibilidad de que Churruca le pusiera "kikos" a su producto inspirados en el personaje del cuento, aunque dato curioso: en la hemeroteca el primer caso de "como el Quico" es de 1935. ¿A ver si va a ser al revés?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

---

**Quico cuestión: ¿Por qué se llama "kiko" al maíz tostado?**

---

La pregunta no deja de tener su aquí, pues previamente hubo que diferenciar entre la palabra "quico" y el nombre de "Quico", ver si estas voces tenían alguna relación con las expresiones "ponerse como el Quico" o "estar como el Quico" (en su relación con la comida, comer de forma exagerada, estar gordo) y a su vez si estos dos "quicos" o cualquier otro tipo procedente de una voz "quico", tenían conexión con la marca registrada Kikos® como exponente para el nombre generalizado para referirse a los granos de maíz tostados, entre medias, también se coló la voz "pancho/s".

---

Las conclusiones fueron: no tienen que ver los apodos de Francisco (Paco, Quico, Kiko, Frasco, Fran, Cisco, Chisco, Pancho, Curro, Xilo...), el nombre de "Kiko" referido a una especie de humano-salvaje, casi un gorila, el nombre de Kiko-Kiko, una especie de espíritu o demonio, la voz "Cicer" (Kiker), como garbanzo, la palabra italiana "Ciccio" para gordito y relacionada "con ponerse como el Quico", y no la fábula que han querido contar de una comilona, las voces "Coccia" (kokia), "Coccidium" (kokki-dium), "Coccode" (koko-de), del gr. (kókkos), (en el sentido de gránulo o grano, por su forma), antiguamente utilizada en medicina para referirse a una pastilla, los distintos tipos de maíz y sus cultivos, y otros tantos e interesantes términos, como "el quico del calcio" (el juego del futbol para los italianos) ni la Diosa "Chicomecoatl" (Siete Serpiente), Diosa del maíz.

---

[image]

---

**RESUMEN**

Después de analizar y relacionar todos los datos por separado desde los que presentan una voz más culta (κικυς - υος - ή,  "kikys - yos - í", fuerza, energía, "Κόκκος" (Kókkos), Lat. Coccus sig. gránulo, grano, baya) hasta el que puede albergar neologismos tratados con un fin comercial, llegué a la conclusión de que tanto la palabra "quico", como el nombre, "Quico", no tenían nada que ver con la marca registrada "Kikos®" para referirse al maíz o su relación con el "comer" o la ingesta, así que aquel sentido de "maíz" con la voz "kiko/s", debería responder o estar basada en otro aspecto o ámbito distinto, quizás, el mercantil y publicitario.

Otra cosa, es que una vez aparecida una palabra, otras puedan tener y aprovechar esa misma sonoridad para aplicarla a objetos o cosas distintas. Así, aunque su escritura sea distinta (homónimos), se escribe en una grafía, tanto de forma más acorde a los nuevos tiempos o modas (por ejemplo, Quico a Kiko) como al contrario, la palabra "quico", formulada para referirse al grano de maíz tostado con una grafía más tradicional.

---

[image]

"*Maíz Loco*", "*Krazy Korn*"

*La palabra "loco" sería la que en último término estaría detrás del nombre "kikos"*

---

La razón última está en las frases publicitarias que aparecían en las bolsas de los "kikos", que explican que "kiko", provendría de un producto tradicional de maíz, llamado "*maíz loco*". Señalar en este sentido, que este "*maíz loco*", no tiene nada que ver con la actual marca conocida como "Elotes Locos" (Elote se refiere a la mazorca fresca, señalada también de forma amplia como "maíz loco").

El "maíz loco" es un tipo de maíz que se siembra en el mes de Febrero, ("Febrerillo loco...", como mes inestable de lluvias), de manera que los granos de una misma mazorca se mezclan y pueden hallarse conjuntamente en ella los que son de color blanco, amarillo, rojo o negro, colores que suelen ser utilizados en el diseño de las bolsas.

Aquel nombre "Maíz Loco", aparecía anunciado gráficamente en las bolsas de la marca "Kikos®" tanto en español como en inglés, en este último caso alterando la propia grafía inglesa "Krazy Korn" (Crazy Corn - Maíz loco) y referido claramente a poner de relieve esa doble "K" ( K_K_), por tanto KiKo fue producto de esta alteración, para mantener visiblemente las dos "K" ( K_K_). Teniendo esto en cuenta, pensé que esa (K_K_), era sin duda el resultado de otro cambio que igualmente llevaría a formar la voz "Ki-Ko" al ser una combinación de palabras tomadas de los dos elementos que componían la expresión ("Krazy (Ky) Korn (Ko)"),"Ky y Ko", referidos al "maíz loco" (KiKos, plural), sin embargo, aún había algo mejor, y era la propia palabra "Kooky", un sinónimo de loco, chiflado, chalado, maniaco, enamorado... que hace referencia y combina ese (Krazy Korn), y que al revés nos da directamente la expresión  "kykoo", "KiKo", una sola palabra que de forma conjunta e igualmente nos da la idea anterior, sea como fuere, en uno u otro sentido, la clave se encontraba aquí, en ese "Krazy Korn", "Maíz Loco" como "Ki-Ko" y en esa especie por querer trasmitir desde la propia marca, la "locura" o el "encanto" por el maíz tostado (aunque esta "locura" no tenga nada que ver con la idea expresada de aquel "maíz loco", aunque si, con la publicidad y el negocio), y que comercialmente, en plural "kikos", acabaría siendo "Kikos®" una marca registrada y por extensión, debido a su popularidad, recogida para referirse en general al maíz tostado.

---

[image]