# How do you say slime (toy) in Spanish

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, juegos

The other day my kids and wife tried making slime at home. I took a picture and I was going to send it to my family in Spain, but I could not figure out how to convey "slime" when it is a toy.

For those who don't understand what I am talking about:

> Slime was a toy product manufactured by Mattel, sold in a plastic trash can and introduced in February 1976.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slime_(toy)) It consisted of a non-toxic viscous, squishy and oozy green or other color material made primarily from guar gum
>
> Source: [wikipedia for slime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slime_(toy))

Unfortunately, although that entry has a Spanish version, the translation for "slime" is "slime". In [wordreference](https://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=slime) we find some potential translations for "slime", like *baba*, *cieno* and *limo*, but none apply to this context.

When I was writing to my family I considered using the brand name of a slime toy ([vulgarización de marca](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19424/5481)) to convey it, like "Blandiblú" <sup>1</sup>, but I couldn't remember the right spelling and I doubted my parents would understand what I was talking about (This toy was around in the late 80s. It's been a long time).

What's the best word to convey the "slime" toy in Spanish? Is there a generic name for it or are we forced to use the name of the most popular toy names like *Blandiblú* (or whichever new ones are now around)?

---

1- *Blandiblú* is the only name and brand I an recall for this toy in Spanish. Probably this was another Mattel toy product.

Comment: In Argentina the brand was Miki Moko.

Answer (score 2):

*Slime* is a wonderful word in English; raw and perfectly descriptive, it is almost onomatopedic, seeming (to the English mind) to beg for exportation. We do have some good options in Spanish, though.

Forgive me as I document for posterity a  duplicate of your preliminary resesrch.

Apparently *slime* has some relation to Latin *limus* (see [etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/word/slime#etymonline_v_23676)), from which root we have [(DRAE)](https://dle.rae.es/limo)

> **limo**
>
> Del lat. limus.
>
> 1. m. Lodo, cieno.

Another option, coming ([possibly, according to etimologias.dechile.net](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?le.gamo)) from a Celtic root, could be closer:

> **légamo**
>
> Quizá del celta *lĕga-, *lĭga- 'sedimento'; cf.irl. ant. lige 'lecho'
> y galés llai 'suciedad'.
>
> 1. m. Cieno, lodo o barro pegajoso.
> 2. m. Parte arcillosa de las tierras de labor.

[Linguee](https://www.linguee.es/ingles-espanol/traduccion/slime.html) suggests some synonyms and offers several translated examples, among which appear attractively:

> **mucílago**
>
> Tb. mucilago.
>
> Del lat. tardío mucilāgo 'mucosidad'.
>
> 1. m. Sustancia viscosa, de mayor o menor transparencia, que se halla en
> ciertas partes de algunos vegetales, o se
> prepara disolviendo en agua materias gomosas.

And simply **baba** (como de caracol), as ukemi mentioned.

*Mucílago*'s definition concords closely with slime's, and the word has a similar descriptive power; but *limo* is shorter, approaching  *slime's* monosyllabic elegance, as well as avoiding any reference to bodily secretions. Then the toy/material that you made could be called: **mucílago casero**, or maybe **mucílago sintético**.

Comment: Dice mi mamá que las niñas vecinas querían hacer "esláim" ayer :) Nosotros vivimos en Chile- son las RRSS que difunden estos anglicismos.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options given here, to varying degrees of specificity:

> El *slime*, o moco de gorila, es una especia de [masilla](https://dle.rae.es/?w=masilla), un *blandiblú* (Blandi Blub) moderno y casero que se puede moldear y customizar a gusto del consumidor.

- [¿Qué es el ‘slime’?](https://www.lavanguardia.com/vida/20180411/442462813197/slime-blandiblu-moco-de-gorila.html) (lavanguardia.com/)

> El *slime* ([baba](https://dle.rae.es/baba) o [barro](https://dle.rae.es/barro) en español) es una especie de blandiblú casero que arrasa en YouTube e Instagram.

- http://relatosdetinta-e.blogspot.com/2017/12/como-hacer-slime.html

Comment: Ni *masilla* ni *baba* ni *barro* me parecen que correspondan a lo preguntado. Y en cuanto al *moco de gorila*, parece que es una marca de gel-fijador https://www.mocodegorila.com/